# Abstract factory - How to remove the dependency of the concrete factory from the client

Tags: design-patterns, solid-principles, ooad

In all the Abstract factory implementations, the calling code(client) has to know the concrete factory. This is just removing the dependency on the products and replacing that dependency with dependency on the concrete factories. Almost all the examples do this. Is there a way to remove this dependency from the client?

Comment: Keep pushing dependencies up until you reach the composition root. The composition root is the only place that should work with concrete.

Answer (score 1):

I see no dependency on concrete factory here:

```
partial class FactoryClient
{
    private readonly IThingFactory _thingFactory;
    public FactoryClient(IThingFactory thingFactory)
    {
        _thingFactory = thingFactory;
    }
    public void Work()
    {
        // ...
        var thing = _thingFactory.Create(1, 2, 3);
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can inject any custom implementation of `IThingFactory` into `FactoryClient`. `FactoryClient` depends only on `IThingFactory` interface.

You can not avoid dependency on the way you create object (parameters and other details) if you actually want to create it. The best you can do - to specify this dependency in interface and find proper implementation on the higher level.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any hard dependency by injecting the factory as a lambda:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new Client(name => new Service(name));
}

public sealed class Client 
{
    private readonly IService service;

    public Client(Func<string, IService> serviceFactory) 
    {
        this.service = serviceFactory("Client");
    }
}

public sealed class Service : IService
{
    public Service(string name) 
    {
        //... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Obviously by creating a class returning the factory, aka a factory factory. But that just replaces the dependency on the factory with a dependency on the factory factory. But that problem is solved easily by making a factory that creates the factory factory. And so on.

Now think about what you gain by doing this.

Comment: Then why not let the client take a dependency on the product it self. Anyways the client has to take a dependency on some class(Concretefactory)

Comment: Do like that. Think about what you gain. Nothing? So what, don't do like that or what?